# Penetration testing approach - Is there a better method?

Tags: penetration-test, opensource

Currently looking at getting some of our web sites pen tested but there are some many companies offering the same, and who are probably using the same tools (not to mention the same wordpress layouts)

I wondering if there is a modern approach that should be looked at, a company that's doing things a bit differently? So for example who would netflix use for pen testing?

I know discussions can be viewed in a negative light but it would be great to get some feedback

Comment: Pen testing services are almost worthless. They will only catch very blatant mis-configuration of your stack. But they're cheap so go for it. The next step up is to hire a consultant with full access to your setup (white-box) to review your security measures. It won't be cheap.

Comment: Companies like netfilx probably utilise a range of tools and processes to make sure that their applications (web, mobile, etc) are secure. They would probably do some of their testing themselves, then have some pen testers and consultants do some of it with various privileges.

Comment: @Atsby you're compairing apples with pears.

Comment: @Atsby It depends on the scope. I've see some network pentesting companies who ran the equivalent of an nmap scan against our external network and collected a fat check. However, I've seen web application pen testing companies that were worth their fee and then some. These tests involved highly skilled and specialized pen testers utilizing human logic and intuition in combination with tools and were highly effective. I actually look forward to reading those reports because the things these people find are amazing. Long story short, you have to shop around till you find the right fit.

Comment: @Grimlockz Better method than what? You need to interview the testers to see what methods they use. They WILL tell you. There are standardized methods testers use that can be a guide. Look to OWASP for specific guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Large tech companies, like Netflix, can afford to have an in-house security team influencing the design and deployment of their software. They don't need to bring in outside help.

Any company without an in-house security team has a few options for pen-testing:

1. White-box - Bring in outside experts to look through everything and secure it, either from the initial design or once the system is finished. This is the most intensive (and expensive) option.
2. Grey-box - Give outside experts some knowledge of the system and let them work from there on their own.
3. Black-box - Give the experts no prior knowledge and let them test the finished system. While this can save time and money if they can't penetrate it, the problems they find might not be easily solvable once the system is finished.